# Changing maker fillcolor in Highcharts scatter graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Is it possible to change the fillcolor of a marker in a Highcharts scatter graph in the load event.  I've researched and can't seem to find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mess with these options...

```
marker: {
    radius: 4,
    lineColor: '#d40000',
    lineWidth: 10
}
```